# How to use certificate authentication in Simple.OData.Client?

Tags: c#, odata, simple.odata, simple.odata.client

How to do certificate authentication in Simple.OData.Client? I have X509Certificate2 which i want to use while calling the api. I use .net framework 4.6.

I did some search and I came to know it is possible to add through HttpClientHandler. But I'm not able to figure out how to do that. Below is the code i have.

```
void foo()
{
   var clientSettings = new ODataClientSettings("");
   clientSettings.OnApplyClientHandler = new Action<HttpClientHandler>(AddClientCertificate);
   var client = new ODataClient(clientSettings);
}

private void AddClientCertificate(HttpClientHandler handler )
{
// I have working code to retrieve the certificate.
X509Certificate2 targetCertificate = RetrieveCertificate();

//TODO : Add the certificate to the HttpClientHandler
}
```

Answer (score 0):

*Short*:
Use the `ODataClientSettings.OnCreateMessageHandler` and return a [WebRequestHandler](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.http.webrequesthandler%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) and setting the `ClientCertificates`.

[I have found the solution from this github issue:](https://github.com/object/Simple.OData.Client/issues/366#issuecomment-317213964)

> Having looked at the code again what you need to do is assign a delegate to OnCreateMessageHandler rather than OnApplyClientHandler as the underlying code creates a HttpClientHandler and you need a WebRequestHandler e.g.

```
var setting = new ODataClientSettings(baseAddresss, credentials) 
{
     OnCreateMessageHandler = { 
     var handler = new WebRequestHandler();
     handler.ClientCertificates.Add(certificate);

     return handler;
     }
}
```

> Note that if you do this, it won't call OnApplyClientHandler so you will have to also allocate any other message handlers in this delegate.
>   I can't easily check this out since I don't have access to a certificate secured site, but there's nothing in the code to suggest this won't work.

Answer (score 0):

Hope one of the below code snippets work fine!

1. `X509Certificate2 targetCertificate = RetrieveCertificate();
       handler.ClientCertificates.Add(targetCertificate);`
2. `var filePath = rootPath + @"/App_Data/apigee.pfx";

        X509Certificate2Collection certificates = new X509Certificate2Collection();
        certificates.Import(filePath, "test", X509KeyStorageFlags.MachineKeySet | 
        X509KeyStorageFlags.PersistKeySet);

        httpClientHandler.ClientCertificates.AddRange(certificates);`